# Jquery/js - load header and footer back after refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `index.html` page that includes a header and a footer. The content of it is changed dynamically through the use of the following function. In order to easily share the URL, I have included / implemented `history.pushState`.

Please have a look at the following script:

```
<script>
    function getfile(data) {
        var file= '/file/'+data+'.html';
        $('#content').load(file);
        history.pushState(null, null, file);
    }
</script>
```

This menu also in index.html

```
<a href="#" onclick="getfile('home')">Home</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getfile('test')">Test</a>
<a href="#" onclick="getfile('aboutme')">About Me</a>

<div id="content"></div>
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that the header and the footer within this index.html cannot not be visible after refresh; therefore, my question is, how could I be able to solve this problem so that the header and the footer re-appear again after refresh?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what it should do?

Comment: I don't pushState works like that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState%28%29_method

Comment: do you have any life code?

Comment: I have a index.html and subpages in another directory.All style attribute like css , header and footer I just put in index.html. In there,just content from subpages is dynamicly changed by using load function. The url is static,just localhost/test/index.html. So,from this way I have a problem to share the url,so I have implemented history.pushState() . The url became change to dynamic :localhost/test/file/home.html. The problem,the styles,header and footer that I was setup in index.html  is gone when I try refresh page.

Comment: So,here I want to know,how method that I have to do to makesure it can hold index.html even the page have dynamic url.